# Serverless Jade templating with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I understand client-side template rendering is a controversial subject, but when coding for compatibility with all web servers, it's a necessity.

I'm after a simple solution for rendering jade templates using angularjs...
Here is a over-simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/BqnR6/

```
angular.bootstrap(document)
```

The example renders a single page and bootstraps angular to evaluate the elements. What I'm after is a solution that uses routing to call up jade files, render them and then evaluate with angularjs.

Is there a way or a workaround to achieve this functionality?

Please note that the rendering of the templates needs to be serverless (ie no nodejs).

Comment: controversial, why? Would a solution whereby everything is in one page work for you? The templates could all be in script tags

Comment: The app uses a single page already (much like the example). I need to render the templates and have the ng- attributes be evaluated and used by angular.

Comment: should be able to compile them and push them into `$templateCache`. If the `templateUrl` exists in `$templateCache` it gets pulled from there first to save unneeded ajax calls. Use script tags. Alternatively replace all the script tag innerhtml with jade compiled html before bootstrapping angular

Comment: Ok I understand the logic there. I'm not looking for a copy pasta, but if you could answer with some example code that would be most helpful as I'm just starting out with angular. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that you embed all your templates into angular `ng-template` script tags:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html" class="angular-template">
       <!-- jade template --></script>
```

The angular convention for this is the ID of `type="text/ng-template"` is a valid template URL and if found angular will pull from script tag before it would attempt to get via ajax

Before bootstrapping angular compile innerHtml of these script tags

```
var templates = document.querySelectorAll('.angular-template')
for (i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
  templates[i].innerHTML = jade.compile(templates[i].innerHTML.trim())()
}
```

Example app using `ng-view` for routing:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html' /* note is same as script tag ID above*/
  });

});

app.controller('testApp', function($scope){
  $scope.title="See script tag for template";
   $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
})

angular.bootstrap(document, ['plunker'])
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/i5xnjOX8m0ChMEge4J2i?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: really all in the amazing capabilities built into angular.... i just shed some light on them for you